# C# Multithreaded Proxy Checker

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, backgroundworker

so got a new problem...

I'm writing a multithreaded proxychecker in c#.

I'm using BackgroundWorkers to solve the multithreading problem.

But i have problems coordinating and assigning the proxys left in queue to the runnning workers. It works most of the time but sometimes no result comes back so some proxys get 'lost' during the process.

This list represents the queue and is filled with the ids of the proxys in a ListView.

```
private List<int> queue = new List<int>();

private int GetNextinQueue() 
    {
        if(queue.Count > 0) 
        {
            lock (lockqueue)
            {
                int temp = queue[0];
                queue.Remove(temp);
                return temp;
            }
        }
        else 
            return -1;
    }
```

Above is my method to get the next proxy in queue, i'm using the lock statement to prevent race conditions but i am unsure if its enough or whether it slows the process down because it makes the other threads wait...
(lockqueue is an object just used for locking)

So my question is, how is it possible that some proxys are not getting checked(even if the ping fails the checking should return something, but sometimes theres just nothing) and how i can i optimize this code for performance?

Here's the rest of the code which i consider important for this question http://pastebin.com/iJduX82b

If something is missing just write a comment

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in simple elegance, use a queue:

```
    private Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
    private int GetNextinQueue()
    {
        lock (queue) { return queue.Count > 0 ? queue.Dequeue() : -1; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, really beautiful solution.

And Thanks to all others for your help, i greatly appreciate that but sadly i can only accept one answer.

The problem with the "lost" proxies is solved now i think.

Answer (score 4):

The check for queue.Count should be performed within the lock statement. Otberwise you may check that queue.Count > 0, but by the time you are able to enter the lock, another thread may have removed an item from the queue, and you are then going to call Remove on a possibly empty queue.

You could modify it to:

```
private int GetNextinQueue() 
    {
        lock (lockqueue)
        {
            if(queue.Count > 0) 
            {
                int temp = queue[0];
                queue.Remove(temp);
                return temp;
            }
            else 
                return -1;
        }
    }
```

Basically, if you want to guard access to a data structure with a lock, make sure that you guard ALL reads and writes to that structure for thread-safety.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. All accesses to the `queue` field need to go inside a `lock (lockqueue)` block -- this includes the `if (queue.Count > 0)` line above. It's not a question of performance: your application won't work if you don't acquire the lock wherever necessary.
2. From your pastebin, the call to `RunWorkerAsync` looks suspicious. Currently each `BackgroundWorker` shares the same arguments array; you need to give each one its own copy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
private int GetNextinQueue()  
{ 
    int ret = -1;
    lock (queue)
    {
        if (queue.Count > 0)  
        { 
            int temp = queue[0]; 
            queue.Remove(temp); 
            ret = temp; 
        } 
    } 
    return ret; 
}
```

I wouldn't worry about performance with this - it's true that other threads will block here if one thread holds the lock, but removing an `int` from a List doesn't take very long.

Also, you don't really need a `lockqueue` object - since `queue` is the object you want to lock access to, just use it.

Comment: "Also, you don't really need a lockqueue object - since queue is the object you want to lock access to, just use it." - Don't do this; lock on a separate `object` instance instead. This is a defence against other class authors who may use `lock (this)` internally.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: `lock (this)` would be considered bad programming practice (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx), and I doubt that the authors of `List` would have done this.

Comment: More from MSDN: "Strictly speaking, the object provided to lock is used solely to uniquely identify the resource being shared among multiple threads, so it can be an arbitrary class instance. In practice, however, this object usually represents the resource for which thread synchronization is necessary."

Comment: I can't speak for the developer of the `List` class, but you can't be safe in general: (a) the C# compiler itself imposes `lock (this)` on you, in the form of its generated `add_Event` and `remove_Event` methods; and (b) you don't find out that the developer _didn't_ use `lock (this)` until it's too late.